# Update PostGIS after updating GDAL?

Tags: postgis, gdal, mapserver, postgis-2.0, update

I am using PostGIS 2.0 and I want to use the raster functionality through mapserver. It seems as if the latest official GDAL release 1.9.1 has an unstable PostGIS raster driver, as pointed out in a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34829/access-postgis-raster-layer-through-mapserver). After posting a ticket, was [advised on github](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/4485#issuecomment-9109659) to update GDAL from trunk for this to work. I did that but I still get the same error. Thus, my question is:

Is it necessary to build PostGIS again from source after updating GDAL for that update to become effective in PostGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During configuration PostGIS is looking for GDAL, the GDAL-config-file that is:
http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#installation_configuration

So yes, I think you need to build PostGIS again; I don't know about a way to point PostGIS to a different/new version of GDAL.

Comment: That's true, I did use that flag for pointing PostGIS to my previous local GDAL install. But since my new GDAL trunk installation is at the same place (replacing the previous one), I wondered if it might not be necessary to build PosgGIS again...

Comment: Yes.  Rebuild PostGIS again as that is always the safest option.  If you're running GDAL trunk, things should work.  It works far better for my projects than 1.9.x